# YouCompleteMe completed failed

Tags: youcompleteme

```
➜  YouCompleteMe git:(master) ./install.py --clang-completer
Searching Python 3.7 libraries...
ERROR: Python headers are missing in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Headers.
```

I used brew to install python and have not downloaded Xcode

Answer (score 6):

Ended here after having the same problem. The problem in my case was that the python version that was being used was not the correct one. So even after executing:

```
brew reinstall python3
```

I was getting the error.

What finally fixed the issue was to explicitly state which python interpreter to use:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.9 install.py --all
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to close iTerm and re-open it. So if reinstalling python3 didn't work, try this or alternatively:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem because of multiple python installations on my machine, one is anaconda python, another is standard python.

I will introduce every step I've done to deal with it.

At first, I used anaconda Python to build YCM.  The YCM Server cannot be started and I got the cause from this [issue](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/3331). But when I tried to install YCM using standard Python with the command:

```bash
$ /usr/bin/python3 install.py --go-completer --clang-completer --go-completer
```

The result of execution is an error message as follows:

```bash
ERROR: Python headers are missing in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers.

The installation failed; please see above for the actual error. In order to get more information, please re-run the command, adding the --verbose flag. If you think this is a bug and you raise an issue, you MUST include the *full verbose* output.

For example, run:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /Users/jianxue/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py --go-completer --clang-completer --go-completer --verbose
```

I was so confused for a long time. And at last, I tried to deactivate the anaconda python, and the standard Python was the default one now.

```bash
python3 install.py --go-completer --clang-completer --go-completer
```

Succeed! I guess anaconda overrides the python configurations. Although I used the standard python, the c header for python still couldn't be found by OS.